# Write annotation to guard a method from being called when parameters are invalid

Tags: java, annotations

Can I have an annotation for a method that when its parameters are null, just do nothing, effectively as not being invoked?

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework ? Spring ? java validation framework?

Comment: You can, but you would some how need to use a proxy around your method to see if those parameters are null.

Comment: @Kal No, I don't use any framework, I want to do this, because I want methods to fail safe, instead of throw NPE at runtime, too many defensive check on null just clutter my codes, in my project we got tons of input from collections, everything can be null, so I want to try whether it works.

Comment: What does it mean "just do nothing" in the case of method that returns, say, an int?

Comment: It's not being called, actually in my case, they're just side effects that won't return anything. I think throw an assertion error should be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is using interfaces and dynamic proxies. Annotations do nothing other than add metadata. You're going to have to add code to act based on the annotation.

You'd have to do a few things --

Create an interface

```
public interface IService {

     @ValidateNull // Your custom annotation
     public void yourMethod(String s1);
}
```

When using the implementation, instantiate it as a JDK Proxy.

```
IService myService = (IService)java.lang.Proxy.newInstance(ServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader(),
                           ServiceImpl.class.getInterfaces(), 
                           new YourProxy(new ServiceImpl());
```

Now, you can via reflection, capture all invocations of your method in `YourProxy` class.

```
 public YourProxy implements InvocationHandler {
public Object invoke(Object arg0, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(ValidateNull.class)) {
                   //Check args if they are null and return.
            }
     }
 }
```

If you dont want to do this, then you're looking at more heavyweight frameworks such as AspectJ  / Spring AOP.

Comment: You don't *have* to use interfaces.  Any non-final method can be proxied at runtime with things like cglib, and compile-time weaving can advise basically anything.  Interface based JDK proxies are certainly the easiest to grok and apply the least "black magic" to your project though!

Comment: @Affe -- Good point. I'll edit my post to more accurately reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Annotations in and of themselves are nothing but data.  They don't "do" anything.  There are a number of different ways you can have a run time framework that interprets annotations and accomplishes the functionality you're looking for.  The most common technique would be what's called Aspect Oriented Programming, where you alter the behaviour of program components based on metadata.

[aspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) is a full featured library that allows you to change the behaviour of just about anything!  You wouldn't even technically need an annotation will full aspectJ, there are lots of different ways to 'match' methods that you want to alter the behaviour of.

[SpringAOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) is a more limited subset of the functionality provided by aspectJ, but it is also easier to use and add to your project as a consequence!